# Kibana Simple Graph Without Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am Using ELK to show graphs on kibana .
I have data set  Below

> ID|A|B
>   6|5|200
>   5|15|110
>   4|25|90
>   2|50|70
>   3|70|50
>   1|100|40

I want Line Graph without any use of Aggregation.
Any Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to get each value into its own field via logstash.  Check out the csv{} filter, which should work with pipe-delimited values as well.

Then, in your kibana visualization, you can add multiple y-axis buckets to display each line.  On the left side are two sections - one for the y-axis, and one for the x-axis.  Add multiple y-axis values for each data series.